# Laravel select a picture by email address in blade view

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel dashboard i have value email address who is message sender, what is the best way show image from array by that value in blade view?

for example

```
$picture = array (
                   '1@email.com', '1.jpg',
                   '2@email.com', '2.jpg',
                   '3@email.com', '3.jpg'
                  );
```

in blade

```
<img src="{{ asset('/images/1.jpg') }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add keys and values ​​to the array:

```
$picture = array (
                 '1@email.com' => '1.jpg',
                 '2@email.com' => '2.jpg',
                  '3@email.com' => '3.jpg'
                 );
```

then read the value with the key:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/images/'.$picture['1@email.com']) }}
```